# Why are weekly reputation scores for the current week (Feb 27 - ...) severely wrong on Stack Apps?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-leagues

The [blog post introducing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-users-page/) the redesigned user pages triggered me looking at [my user page at Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/users/377/steffen-opel?tab=reputation) and much to my surprise I'm listed amongst the [top 14% this week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/37/week/stackapps/2011-02-27/377#377) with 280 reputation, despite no activity of mine but plenty of others. Looking closer at the respective league table for [Feb 27, 2011 - Mar 2, 2011](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/37/week/stackapps/2011-02-27?sort=reputationchange) shows other completely unreasonable entries, e.g.:

- [George Edison](https://stackapps.com/users/18/george-edison?tab=reputation) is certainly capable of amassing quite some reputation in a short time frame, but the listed 1,912 reputation in just 4 days seem a tiny bit too much ;)
- Likewise [Sky Sanders](https://stackapps.com/users/14/sky-sanders?tab=reputation) used to gain lots of reputation in a short time frame as well, but (unfortunately) hasn't even been active since February 1, so the listed 1,735 reputation are definitely off as well.

The reputation tab targeted for all three profile links above does show the correct (i.e. much lower) reputation gained in recent days.

For reference here is the 'complete' picture ;)

[image: Weekly league table for Stack Apps with completely unreasonable reputation scores]

The one thing that obviously springs to mind is the [system-wide recalc of reputation scores][8] that happened around February 27 indeed; could it be that this 'touches' dates of affected posts/votes eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed!  I used the wrong settings on the rep leagues recalc, because I didn't realize StackApps has +10 rep for question upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix and +1 for adding the explanation, always appreciated!

Comment: For the curious: some [more details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86360/why-is-cody-brocious-at-the-top-of-the-weekly-league/86400#86400) of how this works.