# Is the weekly league skewed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

The [weekly Stack Overflow league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stack-overflow) shows [Cody Brocious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4977) as having gained 3,356 reputation so far this week, although his [user reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4977/cody-brocious?tab=reputation) suggests under 100. He's nowhere to be seen on the Users page, so this only appears to be affecting the league calculations.

Aside from fixing the bug, I'd be really grateful if the SO team could give us a bit of insight as to what's happened - if it's non-security-related etc, of course. It's always fun to hear a bit about the root cause of an odd bug :)

Comment: @Jon *I'm a reverse-engineer* in his profile could be a clue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84951/1-273-rep-in-a-single-day-a-record

Comment: @Richard: Possibly the same underlying problem, but this *isn't* showing on the Users page; only on the leagues.

Comment: For my own account it's too high as well, and shows over 4 times my actual weekly score ([41.000](http://i.imgur.com/z5LzV.png) rather than the actual lousy 9.000).

Comment: @Jon: I get the feeling you're [working on something](http://stackapps.com/questions/2325/reputation-query-doesnt-match-that-on-so) :)

Comment: @George: Nope, I just noticed that my rep tracker was "off" yesterday.

Comment: Any chance [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81501/why-are-weekly-reputation-scores-for-the-current-week-feb-27-severely-wro) is related? Maybe David's fix fell apart or was overwritten somehow..

Comment: FWIW: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448673/how-do-emulators-work-and-how-are-they-written/448689#448689) *was* CW (due to numerous edits) 'til a few days ago (when it was removed by a moderator upon request). That alone should account for a pretty massive jump... AFAIK, it scored at or just under 100 when the CW conversion was triggered.

Comment: That is indeed the reason behind this.  I only got a couple upvotes (maybe 5 or 6?) before it went CW.  So yes, this is right-ish for the week.  Don't worry Jon, you'll be back in the lead next week ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way [StackExchange.com leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) work are fairly simple: look at the total *now*, use that value, do the same tomorrow, the day after, etc.

Leagues are calculated from one day to the next by looking at the **total reputation** each user had.  Now, unfortunately that means when a user's rep is recalced on the site-side of things (where we *do* fix all history), the net total difference from this interval to last on the league side won't match up if there was a change.

In this particular user's case he was affected a great deal by a bug in the system from quite a while ago where votes didn't *always* line up to the posts owners.  This was fixed, and resulted in a recalc for all affected users (around 2,000 on SO).  As you can see from this user, some of the oldest users got a measurable rep boost from these previously-unassociated votes.

At the time that recalc happened, Cody went from 10,648 to 13,594 rep...which is the jump you see in the "total-only" league view.  <s>I'll talk with David today and see if we can do anything about the leagues, it's not a simple operation to fix history though so no promises there yet.</s>

---

*Update:* [David](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146719/david-fullerton) recalced the user's reputation leagues on [the SE.com side](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow), all is well now.

Comment: +1 for *it's not a simple operation to fix history*

Comment: So in other words.... the government is run by lizard men?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - much appreciated :)

Comment: @Jon - Update, now fixed!

Comment: Don't want to spoil the party (and I don't care about my listing), but just for your information: for the current week [my SE score](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2011-04-03/84237?sort=reputationchange#84237) is still 41, while it's really just 9 (a lousy [10](http://stackoverflow.com/users/84237/arjan?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time), minus one cast downvote). That's either 32 too many, or more than 4 times too high. ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, you might want to check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/stack-exchange-user-leagues-not-correct.